# "Stuff like" followed by list... "is" or "are"?

Tags: grammar

I'm feeling kind of stumped on this, even though I think I know the answer. If I had written this sentence, I would just rephrase it to avoid the issue, but I came across it and found myself wondering.

The sentence:
"All that stuff like cars and planes is releasing carbon dioxide."

At first glance, it seemed wrong and I immediately thought it should be using "are" instead of "is". But then I stopped and thought about it and realized that it's likely correct, since the sentence would be "All that stuff is releasing carbon dioxide", which is correct, if I took out the examples. It just sounds really awkward and wrong the way it is. Is there any grammatical rule that would justify using "are" in this context? Would it make a difference if the list was longer, like if the sentence was "All that stuff like cars, planes, and factories is/are releasing carbon dioxide"? Or is just a correct grammatical sentence that sounds bad?

Comment: It's gonna "sound bad" to some people regardless of the plurality, because ***stuff*** is such a "casual" usage. And there is no absolute rule, anyway. I'd sidestep the problem and replace ***stuff*** by ***things*** - much more sophisticated, and the plurality problem just vanishes.

Comment: Twinning 'stuff' with 'like A and B ...' sounds very awkward anyway. Think of 'all that furniture like tables and chairs' for a less inherently casual noncount noun forced to correspond to a list of plural-form count nouns: it's still awkward. I'd go further than FF and go with 'Forms of transport such as cars and planes ...'.